# Add-Content - make it 'safe' ? noclobber?

Tags: powershell

So I ran this:

```
(dir|get-filehash -Algorithm sha1|select-object hash, path)
```

and piped that into:

```
Add-Content
```

What I was expecting (hoping) for - was 'Add-Content' to give me some text (perhaps to standard-out?) - or at least prompt me for an output file.

What it in fact did was to add text to the end of every file it found.
(I understand why: the Object-Pipeline passed the 'Path' property all the way through to 'Add-Content', so it dutifully wrote it's output to each file.)

My bad: but potentially a 'gotcha' here - is there a way of adding a 'no-clobber' (by default preferably) to 'Add-Content' ?

And what I should have done of course is this:

```
(dir|get-filehash -Algorithm sha1|select-object hash, path)|add-content -whatif
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the results with something like this:

`(dir|get-filehash -Algorithm sha1|select-object hash, path)| Where-Object{$_.Path -eq $yourPathHere} |add-content $yourContent`

Which uses `Where-Object {$_.property -eq $filter}` to only `Add-Content` to the files with the specified property value.

Another option would be to try using the `-Include` or `-Exclude` switches (depending on your cireteria one of these will be a lot better than the other)